# Logic Sign Puzzles

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

One can obtain a total of $16$ using each of the numbers $10, 12, 14$, and $17$ exactly once, combining them using any of the four common operations $+$, $-$, $*$, and $/$ along with parentheses, by writing $10/(17-12)+14$. **Demonstrate how to obtain $2$.**

I know how to do this, but is there any way to do it without bashing?

Comment: 17*10-12*14. No, there is no 'smart' way, just the brute force search. Well, you may slightly shorten the search by noticing that just + and - are not enough, as the result would always be odd...

Comment: Read the tag descriptions and only add the ones that are relevant!

Answer (score 0):

These type of questions do not have any particular method to solve them. You have to derive answers from options if options are given. And in case no options use brute force to solve them like in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no general way to do this. Perhaps this should be expected, as one might think the strategy for doing this in different bases would change with the base. So we must simply guess. I suggest watching: 'The 10,958 problem' by Numberphile.

It is a great video about obtaining values of 1 to 11,111 using the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, and 9, each exactly once, and the operations $\frown$, *, ^, +, /, -, and (). The problem presented in the video is that, for many years, 10,958 was the only natural number on this list for which no solution was known.

The video could possibly spark some ideas that you could use when doing problems like this.

Here is how to do your problem:
$$17*10-12*14$$

Edit 1: I believe I have found a way to check if this is possible to do only with *, / and -. It relates to the Euclidean algorithm. Notice 17(5)-14(6)=1 Bezout. Then 17(5*2)-14(6*2)=2. These produce the numbers in question.